# cypher sum properties of a specific relation

Tags: cypher

I have this simple example in my DB

[image]

The relationship between each Grid-Node has a distance and time property.
The red node, represents a user. I would like to retrieve the closest Taxi for the user.

First i have a query for knowing in which grids i have taxis

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:PICK_UP]->(g:Grid)-[r2:TO*1..3]-(g2:Grid)<-[r3:TRIP|:IS_ON]-(t:Taxi) 
RETURN g2
```

As a result i got Grid3, 7, 8 and 11.
But i would like to retrieve the grids that satisfy the condition `r2.time <= 5`

in this case how can i use the reduce operation:

```
reduce(totalTime = 0, x IN ---?|totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime
WHERE totalTime <= 5
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
MATCH (:User)-[:PICK_UP]->(g1:Grid),
      p = (g1)-[:TO*..2]-(g2:Grid),
      (g2)<-[:TRIP|IS_ON]-(:Taxi) 
WITH g2, REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime
WHERE totalTime <= 5
RETURN g2;
```

Comment: Thank you Nicole, i will try it out

Comment: i tried this query  (I made some changes in the model)  MATCH p=((g:Grid {name: 'Grid3'})-[r:TO*1..2]-(g2:Grid)), (g2)-[r2:LOCATION]-(t:Taxi) 
WITH  t, p,
REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime
WHERE totalTime <= 6
RETURN t, totalTime, nodes(p). I removed the shortesPath, cause there where nodes that did satisfy the condition but they were not displayed. eg.let's suppose that in the previous image there is a (taxi)-[:LOCATED]->(Grid7) with total time g1 to g7 = 6 but it was not displayed

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I'll update the answer to use *..2 instead of shortestPath.